# Did the upgrade after transaction and still nothing ...how to solve this now?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I have done everything possible the Flush and change the name of wallet...But still nothing ?
How Can i get my coins back or make the transfer succsessful ?

Comment: Have you already popped blocks using that ^ guide?